# a task that check's a user's activity

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanna make a way so that a bot can check a user's status when they type a message and give them a role if their status contains specific words. This is my code atm, yes I've enabled priviliged intents and I'm starting the loop command in the on_message event. The thing is that it returns "ctx is a positional argument that is missing :/ now how do I fix that?

````py
@tasks.loop()
async def check(ctx):
  supporter = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Supporter")
  member = ctx.author
  if ".gg/eternalgw" in member.activity:
    await ctx.send(f"I gave {member.mention} the Supporter role for supporting us!")
    await member.add_role(supporter)```
````

Comment: How will you have context in tasks.loop? Either iterate through all members present, or trigger on any message

Comment: okay, I tried triggering it in the on_message statement without tasks.loop but it didnt work, I didnt use ctx in that tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tasks.loop` do not take `ctx` as an argument, because it doesn't make any sense. If you really want to check status with a loop you have to check all members of the guild. But if you just want to execute this code when someone sends a message use the `on_message` event:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  supporter = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Supporter")
  member = message.author
  if ".gg/eternalgw" in str(member.activity):
    await message.channel.send(f"I gave {member.mention} the Supporter role for supporting us!")
    await member.add_roles(supporter)
```

Comment: this doesn't work, I tried doing this before I made a task but it just didn't work.

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 189, in on_message
    if "Dm" in member.activity:
TypeError: argument of type 'CustomActivity' is not iterable

Comment: aight so I converted it to a string and it works now!

Comment: Now the problem is that it's not adding the role :/

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 192, in on_message
    await member.add_role(supporter)
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'add_role'

Comment: and what about `add_roles`? [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.add_roles)

Comment: oh lmao, I literally forgot, it was a typo lol, anyways thanks for helping me!